# How to check if exception is thrown in Integration Test with xUnit (.net core)?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, integration-testing, xunit

I wondering how can I create test (using xUnit in .NET Core 2.2 WebApi) to check if my API Endpoint throws particular exception.

This is what I have so far:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("/values/sample")]
public async Task Sample_WhenCreatingInvalidSampleData_ThenExceptionIsThrown(string url)
{
    // given
    var command = new AddSampleCommand { Name = "test" };

    // when
    var httpResponse = await Client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, command);

    // then
    var stringResponse = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    stringResponse.ShouldContain("DomainException");
    stringResponse.ShouldContain("is not allowed");
}
```

It works fine, but I think my solution is a bad trick.

I did it because I can't catch this exception when is thrown I can only get httpResponse (which is html) then parse and ensure that contains exception name `stringResponse.ShouldContain("DomainException");` and some exception message `stringResponse.ShouldContain("is not allowed");` in this case.

I've no idea how can I do it in different way. Since it won't work

```
Should.Throw<DomainException>(() => Client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, command));
```

Comment: Those are separate concerns between the client and the server. The client wont know anything about an actual exception on the server other than the http response returned. check the status code, and the expected content.

Comment: can you tap into the middleware pipeline? What server are you using?

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Nkosi Solved, check my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Accidentaly I have found solution :D not sure why it works but the most important it helped.

So I had to create my own `Startup` for tests

```
public class TestStartup : Startup
{
    public TestStartup(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
    {
    }
}
```

and I added `TestStartup` usage to `CustomWebApplicationFactory` and I added `ApplicationPart` from original app to configuration

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TTestStartup, TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
    where TTestStartup: class
    where TStartup : class
{
    protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(null)
            .UseStartup<TTestStartup>();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {    
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(TStartup).Assembly);

            // rest configuration
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to that I can easily catch exception via Assertion or `Should.Throw<DomainException>(() => Client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, command));` like i wanted to.